# Apple sign in delegate methods not calling?

Tags: swift, authentication, delegates, apple-sign-in

I implemented apple sign in in separate NSObject class and calling from viewController.Whenever I click apple signing button, signin dialog appears with password field.After filling password dialog, signin dialog dismisses and delegate methods not calling.Any idea why delegates not calling.

**Note:** I added all configurations in Xcode and developer portals.

```
import AuthenticationServices

class AppleSignin: NSObject {
    
    var successCompletionHandler : ResponseCompletionHandler?

    private var authorizationController: ASAuthorizationController?
    
    func signIn(completion: @escaping ResponseCompletionHandler) {
        
       self.vc = vc
       self.successCompletionHandler = completion
       let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
       let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
       request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
       let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
       authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = getWindow()
       authorizationController.performRequests()
       self.authorizationController = authorizationController

    }
}

extension AppleSignin: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

    // Authorization Failed
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        
        successCompletionHandler?(.failure(error))
    }
    
    // Authorization Succeeded
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
    
            var response = SignInResponse()
            response.firstName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName
            response.lastName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.familyName
            response.emailId = appleIDCredential.email
            successCompletionHandler?(.success(response))
            
        } else if let passwordCredential = authorization.credential as? ASPasswordCredential {
            // Get user data using an existing iCloud Keychain credential
            var response = SignInResponse()
            response.firstName = passwordCredential.user
            response.emailId = passwordCredential.password
            successCompletionHandler?(.success(response))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator?

Comment: @George No, in real device.

Comment: Who holds the AppleSigin class?

Comment: view Controller holds the reference of AppleSignIN

Comment: Hey did you find any solution related to this? I am facing the same issue.. sometime delegates not called